# how to redirect from one https domain to another https domain

Tags: ssl, dns

I am trying to redirect from an old domain to a new domain using a DNS redirect, but https protocol refuses to redirect to the new site.  What is the best solution for this problem ?

Is the only way to handle this kind of redirect within the application code on the server?

Comment: It refuses because to do otherwise would be insecure.